# Insert values into two tables that are linked (1:M)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables user and email. One user can have multiple emails so its a seperate table(that contains user_id as part of its primary key).
I would like to insert multiple attributes into user table and one email into email table as well. 
What is the best way to do that with mySQL query.
Is there any single line command that will do that??

If i cant do that with just with mySql I can use php script as well

**Update**
I see that people are misunderstanding my question. 
All i want to do is to `insert` values like username password into my user table and one email into the linked email table (the one linked to the same user)
I wonder what is the best way to do it in mySQL (and if necessarly Php)

I would like the answer to include the mySQL query (and php scrips as well if necessarily)

Comment: So you want a many-to-many relationship between `users` and `emails`?

Comment: no.. I just want to Insert multiple attributes into my user table and the email table that is linked to that user table.

Comment: you can use innner join. All you have to do is inlcude email_id in users table. And the run the inner join query by joinning two tables. Let me know if it deosn't work

Comment: hey could you write the mySQL query code in the answers below so i can accept your answer please?

Comment: i have written the insert statement (see my answer). you want me to write the select statment for you, i can do that also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to do it in a transaction. That way, if the e-mail insert fails the entire transaction will also fail.

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO users (name)
VALUES ('Emil Vikström');

INSERT INTO emails (user_id, email)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'email address');

COMMIT;
```

Comment: this code looks good is LAST_INSERT_ID() part of the php or mysql code (or do i need to write code to get that id myself?)

Comment: This is SQL only. How to query the database from PHP is heavily documented in all PHP tutorials and books, as well as in the PHP manual itself.

Comment: This SQL script does not work with mySQL whether the email exists in the database or not the user gets created. I even tried putting all of the queries on the same line but it yielded the same results.

Comment: Make sure you disable auto-commit (it may be enabled by default). Also make sure the email field have a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: I have set my autocommit=0; (when i SELECT @@autocommit I get 0)  yet It still doesnt work. When the email allready exists it still creates the user.

Answer (score 1):

You should execute multiple SQL INSERT queries.
I think the best way to do multiple operations monolite is to use SQL-transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this;

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ("you username");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
   $generated_userID = mysql_insert_id(); // php function to get the last generated ID by previous result
    $query = "INSERT INTO emails(user_ID, email) VALUES ($generated_userID, "you email value");
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result)  
       echo "email inserted in email table";
     else
      {
        echo "problem inserting in email table";
         return;
       }
 }
 else
 {
    echo "can't insert into users table";
  }
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can insert multiple values and multiple rows, but I never saw somehthing to do muliple insert into different tables.

```
 INSERT INTO example
      (example_id, name, value, other_value)
    VALUES
      (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
      (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
      (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
      (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

The best thing to do is to insert a row into user retreive the user id with `mysql_insert_id` described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)